# Accept incoming call is not working in marshmallow and noughat

Tags: java, android, xml, call

I am working on an app caller screen for incoming calls. I am not able to accept incoming calls on android marshmallow and nougat API level 23 to 25.

public void acceptCall() {
        TelecomManager telecomManager = null;

```
    //API level >=26
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        telecomManager.acceptRingingCall();
    }

    //API level >=22
    else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        try {
            Runtime. getRuntime (). exec ("input keyevent " +
                    Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Runtime.exec(String) had an I/O problem, try to fall back
            String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
            Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
            Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
            context.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);
        }
    }


    //API level =23 || API=25||API=26
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 ||
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       //what code should i do here?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `TelecomManager`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#acceptRingingCall()

> Note that access to some telecom information is permission-protected. Your app cannot access the protected information or gain access to protected functionality unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in its manifest file. Where permissions apply, they are noted in the method descriptions.

The call to `acceptRingingCall()` is protected by permissions which are classified as "dangerous". On Android versions Marshmallow (API 23) or newer, you will have to request the permission at runtime as well as have it in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Updates from Google :

```
telecomManager.acceptRingingCall();
telecomManager.acceptRingingCall(false);
telecomManager.endCall();
```

All these three commands are deprecated on and from Android Q

[click to verify here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#acceptRingingCall())

[image]